# Visual Basic get selected items

Tags: vb.net

In visual basic, i'm attempting to retrieve all of the selected items rather than just one. 
This is the code before attempting this process.

```
            For Each line As String In lines
                If line.Contains(lbActiveKeys.SelectedItem) Then
                    lines.Remove(line)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
```

I was unable to figure out how to check if the line contains any of lbActiveKeys.SelectedItems* (List Box)
I tried doing nested loops but all i got were errors.

Any ideas what the best way to accomplish this would be?

Cheers.

Comment: What is the underlying type of your lines object? A list of what type?

Comment: A string list is used

Comment: Look at my answer. Try with lbActiveKeys.SelectedItem.Value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work it the reverse way and iterate through the SelectedItems collection.  This should work:

```
    For Each Item As String In lbActiveKeys.SelectedItems
        Dim SearchString As String = Item
        If Lines.Contains(Item) Then
            Lines.Remove(Lines.Find(Function(x) x = SearchString))
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Perfect, Good on you! Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: note this is different matching from the original as this will only remove the item if it is an exact match whilst the original removed the item if the string contained the selected string

Comment: If necessary changing this line like this,`Lines.Remove(Lines.Find(Function(x) x.Contains(SearchString)))`, should work

Comment: it wont work as it the match is not exact then the if fail so you would have to remove the if as well.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with linq:

```
lines = lines.Where(Function(x As String) As Boolean
                        Return Not lbActiveKeys.SelectedItem.Cast(Of String) _
                                   .Where(Function(y) As Boolean
                                              Return x.Contains(y)
                                          End Function).Any()
                    End Function).ToList()
```

It selects items where they do not intersect with the selected items list where selection is determined by whether one string contains the other.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need lbActiveKeys.SelectedItem.Value since you want to compare their string values not the entire selected object... You might also want to make ther case the same and trim to be sure they compare properly:

```
For Each line As String In lines
   If line.ToLower().Contains(lbActiveKeys.SelectedItem.Value.ToLower()) Then
       lines.Remove(line)
       Exit For
   End If
Next
```

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Public member 'Value' on type 'String' not found.

Comment: What is the type of lbActiveKeys? Is it not a ListBox?

Comment: It is a list box, on the form.